# Java ExecutorService callback on thread terminate

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I am using cached thread pool ExecutorService to run some asynchronous background tasks. I've provided my ThreadFactory that hands out threads to the ExecutorService (whenever it needs them). My understanding of the cached thread pool is that after the thread is sitting idle for 60 seconds it is termniated by the ExecutorService.

I want to perform some state cleanup when my thread is about to be terminated. What is the best way to achieve this? The ExecutorService does not readily provide hooks into the thread's lifecycle.

I don't want to shutdown my ExecutorService - useful for running tasks as and when they come.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new MyThreadFactory());

// Do some work
executor.submit(new MyCallable());

// Need a way for the ExecutorService to notify me when it is about to
// terminate my thread - need to perform some cleanup
```

Thanks,

Shreyas

Comment: +1 for interesting question. I wonder if a finalizer would work?

Comment: @Rom1, someone had posted in answer suggesting implementing `finalize`. I think it is too bad they deleted it. What should be noted is that using `finalize` means incurring some performance hits in the GC and JVM.

Comment: I tried to use the finalize approach but it didn't work. The method was not getting called.

Comment: @Tim, sure, the accepted answer looks a lot better than meddling with finalizers

Comment: It's more or less similar to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826212/java-executors-how-to-be-notified-without-blocking-when-a-task-completes/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your `ThreadFactory` code, create the instance of `Thread` such that it will `try` to do the work of the `Runnable` it is created for and then `finally` do your cleanup work. Like this:

```
public Thread newThread(final Runnable r) {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                r.run();
            } finally {
                //do cleanup code
            }
        }
    };
    return t;
}
```

Comment: Another option is to use a fixed size thread pool and never clean up.  Freed memory is never passed back to the OS, so you may be adding complexity without a benefit.

Comment: but if the thing that needs to be cleaned up is a database connection, you can't just 'never clean up.'