# how to strand executorservice

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

My program flow is like this:
I need to sequential processing per user's request
In C++ I will use boost asio and one strand per user but I had to code in java
So I intend to create one SingleThreadExecutor per user and post user's task into it's executor 
But if user num get big I think this approach will slow because of the big number of thread
So I looking for alternative solution, the other approach in my head is one queue per user and some how tosh that queue to a fixed thread pool, need advise here, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution just 5 minute after I post question T_T
It's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826212/java-executors-how-to-be-notified-without-blocking-when-a-task-completes), CallbackTask  approach look promising.