# How to wait inside a method, till other method is completed

Tags: java, proxy

Let's say we have this code:

```
int number;

public void onMessageReceived(int num) {
    number = num;
}

public int getNumber() {
    sendMessage("number")
    return number;
}
```

you get the Message only after lets say 1 second.

How do you "wait" until you get the "number" without freezing the Main-Thread?

```
public int getNumber() {
    sendMessage("number")
    //WAIT TILL I GET THE "NUMBER"
    return number;
}
```

Comment: from where you are calling onMessageReceived() method?

Comment: Can you make it more clear.. Where your program starting point sequence of execution of your methods makes confusion

Comment: The problem is I'm using Bungeecord and spigot libs... I can't really modify them, because updating would be a pain

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use something like Java Future.

Have a look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) or read up this simple [example](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/01/how-to-use-future-and-futuretask-in-Java.html).

Comment: Look's good! Just what I needed... Going to try it and mark it as correct if it works.

Comment: Oh oh.. It still freezes the thread which doesn't me to receive the Message

Comment: @DenRandomstuff Maybe you could show the code that you tried? Also, it really depends on the context, i.e. on the app that you're running. If it's a web app, then of course it will need to block at some point. If it's a desktop application, the main UI thread should still be running.

Comment: Its a spigot(bukkit) server, everything is on 1 thread which is annoying, but meh

Comment: Java Future is usually used when you have a complex computation, and you can basically "start" it at the start of the computation, do lots of other things, and when you actually need the value, you basically block.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of asynchronous calls need some callback mechanisms.

You may need to use an observer design pattern that subscribe into an event call.

See this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm)

Or try to use CallbackTask like in this question:

[java-executors-how-to-be-notified-without-blocking-when-a-task-completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826212/java-executors-how-to-be-notified-without-blocking-when-a-task-completes)

Answer (score 0):

You should use join method...

When a thread calls join() on another thread, the currently running thread will wait until the thread it joins with has completed.

Answer (score -1):

May be recursive methodlogy

```
public int getNumber() {

 while(number!=0)
 getNumber(); //Assuming number will not be null till you get positive integer greater than a zero same method will get recalled.
 sendMessage("number")

return number;
}
```

When `onMessageReceived(int num)` called then you can find a positive integer in `number` so that it will countinue the execution

Comment: That would endup spamming the "number" request

Comment: Another weakness in your approach: it puts "special meaning" on the value of 0. Long story short: don't try to provide "answers" that just solve the problem. Always consider for yourself the "option space"; and determine the solution that has the best "pro vs. con" ratio.

Comment: @Jägermeister If you can highlight the weakness that would be very helpful :) Will try to find the `pro and con` :)

Comment: What I mean is: what if "0" is a perfect valid result coming from `getNumber()`. You **assume** that 0 can be used to distinguish "result received" vs. "still waiting". You are making implicit assumptions here; and that is bad style.

Comment: @Jägermeister I assumed because OP didnt provide much information regarding that, anyhow i will update my answer. Thank you for clarification :)