# Why CompletableFuture 's thenAccept() not running on the main thread

Tags: java, completable-future

I process the long running operation inside the CompletableFuture's supplyAsync() and get the result into thenAccept(). In some times thenAccept() perform on the main thread but some time it running on the worker thread.But I want run thenAccept() operation only on the main thread. this is the sample code.

```
private void test() {

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    CompletableFuture<String> cf1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("supplyAsync | I am running on : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return "Hello world";
    }, executorService);

    CompletableFuture<Void> cf3 = cf1.thenAccept(s -> {
        System.out.print("thenAccept | I am running on : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println(" | answer : " + s);
    });

    cf3.thenRun(() -> {
        System.out.println("thenRun | I am running on : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println();
    });

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    App app = new App();
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        app.test();
    }
}
```

result is :

```
supplyAsync | I am running on : pool-1-thread-1
thenAccept | I am running on : main | answer : Hello world
thenRun | I am running on : main

supplyAsync | I am running on : pool-2-thread-1
thenAccept | I am running on : main | answer : Hello world
thenRun | I am running on : main

supplyAsync | I am running on : pool-3-thread-1
thenAccept | I am running on : pool-3-thread-1 | answer : Hello world
thenRun | I am running on : pool-3-thread-1
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Thanks. Assume in side the thenAccept() method  i access shared resource. Then i have to consider about thread safety of the resource. Vert.x 's executeBlocking is similar to this. They handle this properly.

Comment: Well, 'properly' may be in the eye of the beholder. If you're accessing shared resources in an asynchronous fashion it seems you need to be concerned about thread safety. Perhaps you should only allow access to the shared resource via a monitor which schedules tasks on a single thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in the JavaDoc of [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html). The interesting part is the one about the **CompletionStage** policies.

There you find that using the *non-async* method results in a kind of either-or-scenario. If you then take a look in the implementation you will end up in the non-public part of the Java Runtime. There is some **UNSAFE** handling that implies that there may happen some kind of race condition.

I would suggest using **thenAcceptAsync()** and **thenRunAsync()** variants and pass your *executorService* variable to both calls.

Comment: Does the main thread exit before all of the `CompletableFuture` tasks are completed? Also, can you post the 'interesting part' of the `CompletableFuture` javadoc?