# Use CompletableFuture to execute single or multiple Callables and avoid blocking

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I execute a few callables through `ThreadPoolExecutor`. If thread list contains only 1 callable then I directly call `call` method of my `CallableService`. If list contains more than 1 callables then I execute all those threads in parallel via thread pool executor.

How can I achieve this with Java 8 CompletableFuture? And if `future.get()` is enhanced to avoid blocking, that will be a plus.

```
private static ThreadPoolExecutor myThreadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, 100, 5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<>());

public static void execute(List<Callable<Boolean>> threadList) throws Exception {

    List<Future<Boolean>> futureList = null;
    CallableService singleService = (CallableService) threadList.get(0);
    if (1 == threadList.size()) {
        singleService.call();
    }
    else {
        try {
            futureList = myThreadPoolExecutor.invokeAll(threadList);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (null != futureList) {
        for (Future<Boolean> future : futureList) {
            try {
                future.get();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                //do some calculations here and then throw exception
                throw new Exception(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Below link has some good suggestions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31092067/method-call-to-future-get-blocks-is-that-really-desirable

Comment: "And if `future.get()` is enhanced to avoid blocking, that will be a plus" – note that [`#invokeAll(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)) won't return until all the tasks are complete, which means the calls to `#get()` will return quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for `CompletableFuture`, as the way you use the `ExecutorService` is sufficient, though, there are some aspects of the code flow which could be improved. You fetch the first element, even when not needed, and you cast it to `CallableService` for no reason, as you can call the method via the `Callable` interface already. In the other branch you are catching `InterruptedException` and proceeding, so the caller would never know that not all jobs have been executed. And in a straight-forward code flow, you don't need to check the list for `null`:

```
public static void execute(List<Callable<Boolean>> threadList) throws Exception {
    if(1 == threadList.size()) {
        Callable<Boolean> singleService = threadList.get(0);
        singleService.call();
    }
    else {
        List<Future<Boolean>> futureList = myThreadPoolExecutor.invokeAll(threadList);
        for(Future<Boolean> future : futureList) {
            try {
                future.get();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                //do some calculations here and then throw exception
                throw new Exception(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could shorten it further to

```
public static void execute(List<Callable<Boolean>> threadList) throws Exception {
    if(1 == threadList.size()) {
        threadList.get(0).call();
    }
    else {
        for(Future<Boolean> future : myThreadPoolExecutor.invokeAll(threadList)) {
            try {
                future.get();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                //do some calculations here and then throw exception
                throw new Exception(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But that's a matter of preferred coding style. But note that it caught my eye that in the single element case, you're not performing the same exception handling.

---

To use `CompletableFuture`, we need an adapter method, as the convenience method `supplyAsync` requires a `Supplier` instead of a `Callable`. Using a modified variant of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43767613/2711488), we get

```
public static void execute(List<Callable<Boolean>> threadList) throws Exception {
    if(1 == threadList.size()) {
        threadList.get(0).call();
    }
    else {
        CompletableFuture<?> all = CompletableFuture.allOf(
            threadList.stream()
                .map(c -> callAsync(c, myThreadPoolExecutor))
                .toArray(CompletableFuture<?>[]::new));
        try {
            all.get();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            //do some calculations here and then throw exception
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
public static <R> CompletableFuture<R> callAsync(Callable<R> callable, Executor e) {
    CompletableFuture<R> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try { cf.complete(callable.call()); }
        catch(Throwable ex) { cf.completeExceptionally(ex); }
    }, e);
    return cf;
}
```

So we have no `invokeAll` which takes care of submitting all jobs. We have to do this manually, either with a loop or a stream operation. On the other hand, we get a single future via `allOf` representing the completion status, exceptionally if at least one job failed.

Unlike `invokeAll`, which waits for the completion, `allOf` only returns the future so it is the `all.get()` call which waits for the completion. We could do other things before it or even use this property to always perform the first job in the caller thread:

```
public static void execute(List<Callable<Boolean>> threadList) throws Exception {
    CompletableFuture<?> tail = CompletableFuture.allOf(
        threadList.stream().skip(1)
            .map(c -> callAsync(c, myThreadPoolExecutor))
            .toArray(CompletableFuture<?>[]::new)),
        head = callAsync(threadList.get(0), Runnable::run);
    try {
        head.get();
        tail.get();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        //do some calculations here and then throw exception
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

This will always call the first callable in the current thread, as `Runnable::run` used as `Executor` will perform the action immediately in the calling thread. But it's treated uniformly in all other aspects, especially the exception handling. When there is only one job, `allOf` invoke with an empty array will do nothing and return an already completed future, which will have the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks for providing both ways. I'll opt for the first one. 1 question. Is `future.get()` not redundant here as well? Because I just learnt this about `invokeAll()`.

"Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete. Future.isDone() is true for each element of the returned list."

Comment: @TishyTash `future.get()` after `invokeAll`, will not wait, that’s right, but its invocation will throw an exception if the job failed, which is caught and handled in a specific way in your code (“`//do some calculations here and then throw exception␍␊ throw new Exception(e.getMessage(), e);`”), so I assume, this is intentional.

Comment: Oh that's necessary. I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Future.isDone() tells us if the executor has finished processing the task. If the task is completed, it will return true otherwise, it returns false.

```js
 for (Future<Boolean> future : futureList) {
   while(!future.isDone()) 
   {
          doSOmethingElse();
          Thread.sleep(300);//Optional
    }
 try {
                future.get();
        }
    catch (Exception e) 
 {
                //do some calculations here and then throw exception
                throw new Exception(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

But we don't have to worry about that since we get to the point where get() is called after making sure that the task is finished.

Answer (score 0):

> I execute a few callables through ThreadPoolExecutor. If thread list contains only 1 callable then I directly call call method of my CallableService. If list contains more than 1 callables then I execute all those threads in parallel via thread pool executor.

I guess you have already implemented this part. (You might run into memory usage issues if your jobs are heavy and you have 100 threads running as configured. But that is a different problem.)

> And if future.get() is enhanced to avoid blocking, that will be a plus.

For this, you may take this approach:

1. Create another `ExecutorService` whose job will be just to run the `Future.get()` calls.
2. Submit your `Future.get()` to that service as shown below.
3. Shut it down and await termination.

   ```
   if (null != futureList) {
       ExecutorService waitSvc = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
       for (Future<Boolean> future : futureList) {
           try {
               waitSvc.submit( () -> future.get() );
           }
           catch (Exception e) {
               //do some calculations here and then throw exception
               throw new Exception(e.getMessage(), e);
           }
       }
       waitSvc.shutdown(); //This may take some time. You may want to call awaitTermination() after this.
   }
   ```

However, I feel that you should redesign the overall approach of using so many threads, unless this is only a for-learning application.