# Mutithreading task submission

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I want to run a task for 8 hours.
I am using `ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30).`
and after submitting the task I am waiting for  8 hours .
This is the code I have used.

```
task1.get(8,TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

Problem is the code after above statement will be executed after 8 hours . 
I wanted the task to be executed for 8 hour but the statement after that should be printed immediately. Can somebody suggest some way.

Comment: Then switch the 2 statements

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are using ExecutorService and Future slightly incorrectly.

When you submit your task, that is when it may (depending on your thread pool) begin executing. If you want to print something after it has started, that is where you should do it.

Future.get is used to wait retrieve the result (up to 8 hours in your case) so is going to block until it is complete.

Something like (not tested):

```
Callable task = new Callable<String>() {
    // 8 hour task
}

Future<String> future
       = executor.submit(task); // Task may begin here
System.out.println("Task has been submitted, let's wait");
String result;
try {
     result = future.get(8,TimeUnit.HOURS); //
} catch (ExecutionException ex) { 
     // ....
```

Comment: but `get` is blocking invocation and the question was about how to avoid this

Comment: That wasn't what I understood from the question, but maybe you are right. @Rashmi - can you clarify please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CompletableFuture` and use `thenApply` on it. Then the code won't wait on `get` because `get` is blocking method which (in your case) waits maximum **8 hours**

Answer (score 0):

I think this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826212/java-executors-how-to-be-notified-without-blocking-when-a-task-completes) about task completion might help you.

I do agree with @k0ner, use [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) available on Java8. There is an example at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22363245/4184102) about using `CompletableFuture`. The `get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` method has a *blocking* behavior and that's not what you want to.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Java 6. So I cannot use `CompletableFuture`.

I am solving problem with this logic. I have removed the get functionality. 
Inside `run()` method I am getting the `startTime` of the thread being started using `Date` Utility. Then I am checking if 8 hour is over (right now I have tested for 1 min). The task is stored in data structure.

After the time is over I am retrieving the task and cancelling it.

Comment: So just avoid calling `get` in your main thread. You can do this in different thread which waits for the completition. Or you can even print the result in you `task1`. It all depends whether you need (or not) to pass the result somewhere else.