# Android: Repository function returns false using Room

Tags: android, android-room, executorservice

I've added a favourites button to the recyclerview item and using Room to save the favourite data. What's happening is that the Repository function `isFavourites` returns false even if the data exists in the database.

Since Room isn't supposed to run on the main thread, I'm using `Executors` and while logging, I realised that the boolean variable inside the `Executors` method returns true but outside, it returns false.

How do I fix this?

FavouriteDAO.java

```
@Dao
public interface FavouriteDao {

    @Query("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM favourites WHERE id=:id)")
    public boolean isFavourite(int id); 

}
```

FavouriteRepository.java

```
boolean isFavourite(int id) {
            final boolean[] b = new boolean[1];
            Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> {
                b[0] = favouriteDao.isFavourite(id);
                Log.d(TAG, "Favourite is" + b[0]); <--- returns true if data exists
            });
            Log.d(TAG, "Favourite is" + b[0]); <--- returns false always
            return b[0];
        }
```

FavouriteViewModel.java

```
 public boolean isFavourite(int id) {   return mRepository.isFavourite(id); }
```

This always returns false in Activity:

```
  boolean isFavourite = favouriteViewModel.isFavourite(id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking the value of your boolean before the asynchronous task completes, so you're always reading its default value of `false`. You need some sort of callback for when the `Executor` task completes:

[Java executors: how to be notified, without blocking, when a task completes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826212/java-executors-how-to-be-notified-without-blocking-when-a-task-completes)

You could also use RXJava, which has built-in solutions for this.